# Weighted custom loss keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

You can use weighted *MSE* in Keras like this

```
model.fit(sample_weight=weights, loss='mse', ...)
```

I want to use weighted *RMSE* but Keras library doesn't have rmse, I wrote it myself

```
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))
```

but how then to use weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/losses/#creating-custom-losses), it appears that it's done automatically:

> **Creating custom losses:**
> Any callable with the signature *loss_fn(y_true, y_pred)* that returns an array of losses (one of sample in the input batch) can be passed to *compile()* as a loss. **Note that sample weighting is automatically supported for any such loss.**